# Distriqt Share ANE message and url not appearing in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, air, share, ane

When using `Share.service.share("My message", bitmap, url);` I'm not seeing the message or the url appear in the Facebook modal that pops up.

The bitmap is making it through, but the text shown in the modal is the standard Facebook prompt ("Say something about this photo"). Once posted onto the FB wall, the image is not linked to the url supplied by `Share.services.share` call.

**Gmail:** If instead of selecting Facebook I choose Gmail, then all the params make it through to Gmail's compose email screen.

Not sure why Facebook would fail yet Gmail succeed.

Testing on:

- Android 4.4.2
- Air 23.0
- Facebook API 2.5
- Share 3.4.009
- Core 2.5.073

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a limitation of the Facebook sharing policy.

They don't allow you to pre-fill a post with an image or url, unless you go through the Facebook SDK directly.

If you really require this functionality then you'll need to look into implementing Facebook login through the Facebook SDK using an ANE, eg: [com.distriqt.FacebookAPI](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.FacebookAPI).